# Access more than one db with ScalaAnorm with Play

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0

How do I access two separate MySQL databases with ScalaAnorm?

The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm) seems to only provide examples for single db access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would give the second db another name (instead of `default`) in `application.conf` with it's own settings:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url= ...
db.default.user= ...
db.default.password= ...

db.anotherdb.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.anotherdb.url= ...
db.anotherdb.user= ...
db.anotherdb.password= ...
```

Then you can specify which database you want to use like so:

```
DB.withConnnection("default") { implicit connection =>
    // uses the database named "default"
}

DB.withConnnection("anotherdb") { implicit connection =>
    // uses the database named "anotherdb"
}
```